# Exclude code with conditional parameters when a specific dll is missing

Tags: c#, dll, conditional-compilation

I have a program that can be build with different features that are each dependent on a different dll. Right now I disable or enable each of the features by conditional parameters.

But I'm curious if it is possible to do this automatically. So maybe when the specific feature dll is not detected at compiling the conditional parameter gets set and it automatically disables all the associated code.

Is this possible or should I take another approach for dynamically excluding code on compile time?

Comment: It is possible but you have to link to DLL in "manual" way (and if exists). Otherwise Windows loader will return error that some module (dll) is missing and will not run the program.

Comment: What do you mean by a "dll"? Are these the native Windows' dlls that you're using via P/Invoke? Are these the .NET assemblies? Are these statically referenced by your assemblies or loaded dynamically?

Comment: @dymanoid The dlls are own made projects compiled into a dll so probably .NET assemblies? I refer to them with the add reference in Visual Studio so statically.